# Avoid query each time the page is loaded

Tags: caching, web

I work on an educational website in which we show dynamic filters. What does this mean? We now have several course categories that will increase in number in the following weeks.

Right now categories are a string field in each course. I'm planning to model this and create a Categories table. Having done this, it would be pretty easy to load the filters based on the categories we have on the database. However, I see the problem that each time the website is loaded, the query will be made.

I thought of caching these categories but I'm guessing is not the best solution.

Any idea on how can I avoid these queries each time but get this information from the database?

Comment: Are you looking to avoid the query multiple times during the same user session? If so you should store it in a session variable. As it doesn't seem to be sensitive data why not use a cookie if you need it for when the user leaves and returns to the website later?

Comment: [How about MemoryCache?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)